# Streaming Large (5gb) CSV’s FAST (in parallel?) on 16-core Machine?

Tags: python, csv, optimization, parallel-processing, bigdata

I have 30 CSV files (saved as .txt files) ranging from 2GB to 11GB each on a server machine with 16 cores.

- Each row of each CSV contains a date, a time, and an ID.

I need to construct a dense matrix of size datetime x ID (roughly 35,000 x 2000), where each cell is count of rows that had this datetime and ID (so each CSV row’s datetime and ID are used as matrix indices to update this matrix). Each file contains a unique range of datetimes, so this job is embarrassingly parallel across files.

***Question: What is a faster/fastest way to accomplish this & (possibly) parallelize it?*** I am partial to Python, but could work in C++ if there is a better solution there. Should I re-write with MapReduce or MPI? Look into Dask or Pandas? Compile my python script somehow? Something else entirely?

***My current approach (which I would happily discard for something faster):***
Currently, I am doing this serially (one CSV at a time) in Python and saving the output matrix in h5 format. I stream a CSV line-by-line from the command line using:

`cat one_csv.txt | my_script.py > outputfile.h5`

And my python script works like:

```
# initialize matrix
…
for line in sys.stdin:
    # Split the line into data columns
    split =  line.replace('\n','').split(',')
    ...(extract & process datetime; extract ID)...

    # Update matrix
    matrix[datetime, ID] = matrix[datetime, ID] +1
```

**EDIT** Below are a few example lines from one of the CSV's. The only relevant columns are 'dateYMDD' (formatted so that '80101' means jan. 1 2008), 'time', and 'ID'. So for example, the code should read use the first row of the CSV below to add 1 to the matrix cell corresponding to (Jan_1_2008_00_00_00, 12).

Also: There are many more unique times than unique ID's, and the CSV's are time-sorted.

```
Type|Number|dateYMDD|time|ID
2|519275|80101|0:00:00|12
5|525491|80101|0:05:00|25
2|624094|80101|0:12:00|75
5|623044|80102|0:01:00|75
6|658787|80102|0:03:00|4
```

Comment: You need to start by profiling. For example - it's possible to get **much worse performance** if you waste a lot of time seeking on disk due to lots of competing parallel reads. Not so bad for SSD's these days, but you have to consider how the whole system interacts during the processing.

Comment: Can you share few sample lines of CSV file and what matrix you want ? I can try writing it in python map/reduce.

Comment: As said by @JohnLaRooy, this task is disk-bound and parallelizing will worsen things, unless you use several disks (but this can saturate the PCI bus as well).

Comment: Can you consider creating the h5 files at the same time the csv files are written, then merge ?

Comment: Example CSV added to the original post.  Yves, I do not follow your suggestion of creating h5 files at the same time as the csv -- can you clarify? I already have all of the CSV files. I was using h5 as a convenient way to store the script's output matrix.   -Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should probably profile your script to make sure the bottleneck is actually where you think.

That said, Python's Global Interpreter Lock will make parallelizing it difficult, unless you use multiprocessing, and I expect it will be faster to simply process them separately and merge the results: feed each Python script one CSV and output to one table, then merge the tables. If the tables are much smaller than the CSVs (as one would expect if the cells have high values) then this should be relatively efficient.

I don't think that will get you all-caps full-throttle FAST like you mentioned, though. If that doesn't meet your expectations I would think of writing it in C++, Rust or Cython.